# Stable Diffusion (Couldn't Install Torch & Pip Version)

Tags: python, windows, pip, pytorch

I am trying to install and configure Stable Diffusion AI locally on my PC (Windows 11 Pro x64), following the How-To-Geek article, [How to Run Stable Diffusion Locally With a GUI on Windows](https://www.howtogeek.com/832491/how-to-run-stable-diffusion-locally-with-a-gui-on-windows/)

Naturally enough, I've run into problems, primarily (as the code below shows, Torch install and Pip version :)

This is what I get when I run the Stable Diffusion batch file:

```
venv "D:\stable-diffusion-webui-master\venv\Scripts\Python.exe"
Python 3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Commit hash: <none>
Installing torch and torchvision
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "launch.py", line 108, in <module>
    run(f'"{python}" -m {torch_command}', "Installing torch and torchvision", "Couldn't install torch")
  File "launch.py", line 55, in run
    raise RuntimeError(message)
RuntimeError: Couldn't install torch.
Command: "D:\stable-diffusion-webui-master\venv\Scripts\python.exe" -m pip install torch==1.12.1+cu113 torchvision==0.13.1+cu113 --extra-index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cu113
Error code: 1
stdout: Collecting torch==1.12.1+cu113

stderr:   Cache entry deserialization failed, entry ignored
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch==1.12.1+cu113 (from versions: 1.7.0, 1.10.0+cu113, 1.10.1+cu113, 1.10.2+cu113)
No matching distribution found for torch==1.12.1+cu113
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 22.2.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

That's even after I tried the following:

- `pip install -vvv torch`
- `pip3 install --pre torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch_nightly.html`
- `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`

For #2 I get "ERROR: torch has an invalid wheel, .dist-info directory not found".
It's probably worth noting that although I installed the program to my D: drive, I already have python 6.1 (64bit) installed on my C: drive.

I'm an ex-techy (now author) trying to install an image generator on my PC to potentially make a book cover. It probably won't work but it certainly won't if I can't get the thing running so, any help appreciated :)

James

Comment: The issue is almost certainly your `pip` version. Fix that and then see if this works.

Comment: Thanks but how do I fix it? I tried that "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" thing and it says it upgrades ("Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\<userid>\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (21.3.1)") so what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're running the wrong `pip` command then I'd guess. Does `pip3` work?

Comment: Yeah ... I tried: 

pip3 install --pre torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch_nightly.html

 ... I get "ERROR: torch has an invalid wheel, .dist-info directory not found"

James

Comment: So, 

I decided to look up how to install torch which took me to pytorch (I assume that's the same thing). I got all the way through the download and install then got: 

ERROR: Package 'torch' requires a different Python: 3.6.1 not in '>=3.6.2'

What exactly does that mean? Is it saying I need to install a later version of python? A casual search across the web suggests it wouldn't because people are getting the error with later versions of python. 

What version of python do I need (if that's even the issue)?

Comment: `3.6.1 not in '>=3.6.2` means that your version, 3.6.1, is not greater than or equal to version 3.6.2, so it does not meet the requirements. Therefore, it's saying that your Python version must be greater than or equal to 3.6.2 in order to install `torch`. It could be that if you install a version that's too new that it won't work, but you can always just give it a shot.

Comment: @JamesRocks Try uninstalling the old python versions first, then follow the answer chris91 gave. Please follow this short tutorial, it covers everything you need to install Stable Diffusion locally: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6MeJKnbv1ts - doing all that made it work for me.

Answer (score 25):

You need to install Python 3.10.6 (https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.6/python-3.10.6-amd64.exe)

Make sure to choose "add to PATH" when installing or add it manually.

Remove the venv folder from your Stable Diffusion folder that was created with the wrong version of python.

Launch webui-user.bat again and it should work fine.

Comment: Apologies for my late reply, family issues :) I eventually gave up and tried to install it piecemeal:

Install PyTorch on its own but found that python 3.10 doesn't work however python 3.82 does. 

Having installed PyTorch, I then went on to do StableDiffusion (from scratch) and it appears to have installed AOK however, when I try to generate an image, it doesn't seem to be all there, and I get weird error messages like <the following message>

Comment: (ldm) D:\stable-diffusion\stable-diffusion-main>python scripts/txt2img.py --prompt "a photograph of a gopher wearing a wizard hat in a forest, vivid, photorealistic, magical, fantasy, 8K UHD, photography" --plms --n_iter 5 --n_samples 1
Global seed set to 42
Loading model from models/ldm/stable-diffusion-v1/model.ckpt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/txt2img.py", line 344, in <module>
    main()
  File "scripts/txt2img.py", line 240, in main
    model = load_model_from_config(config, f"{opt.ckpt}")

Comment: File "scripts/txt2img.py", line 50, in load_model_from_config
    pl_sd = torch.load(ckpt, map_location="cpu")
  File "C:\Users\JamesCRocks\.conda\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 699, in load
    with _open_file_like(f, 'rb') as opened_file:
  File "C:\Users\JamesCRocks\.conda\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 231, in _open_file_like
    return _open_file(name_or_buffer, mode)
  File "C:\Users\JamesCRocks\.conda\envs\ldm\lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py", line 212, in __init__
    super(_open_file, self).__init__(open(name, mode))

Comment: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'models/ldm/stable-diffusion-v1/model.ckpt'

Apologies for posting over several comments. If there's a better way to do it, please let me know.

Comment: Thank you, this answer worked for me. I also uninstalled the old python version to be sure.

Comment: @JamesRocks It seems you're missing a few files. Please follow this short tutorial, it covers everything you need to install Stable Diffusion locally: https://youtu.be/6MeJKnbv1ts

Comment: Thanks! Your fix worked for me. I was following Kevin Stratvert's video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=onmqbI5XPH8), and he installed Python 3.10.6. But when I got to that step, I installed Python 3.11.1, which led to the torch and torchvision error reported above.

Comment: yeap! pyhthon version was the issue, thanks!

Comment: I met all the "special requirements" already, but did not see the venv folder! You saved me countless hours just by this hint!

Comment: The important fix for me was removing the old 'venv' folder and creating a new one.

Answer (score 2):

I literally tried everything. Manual install of torch, updating pip, checking PATH, reinstalling python. The only thing that worked was restarting my computer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 2):

Steps that worked for me (in the end)

1. download git installer and install
2. open the git-shell and run `git clone https://github.com/automatic1111/stable-diffusion-webui.git`
3. uninstall any version of python-3.10.x
4. download latest version of python-3.10.x
5. right-click that python-installer.exe, from context select: run as admin ...
6. install for *all users* AND check to *add the environment*
7. if you have previous failed attempts,
8. delete the venv directory (wherever you cloned the stable-diffusion-webui, e.g. C:\Users\you\stable-diffusion-webui\venv)
9. check the environment variables (click the Start button, then type “environment properties” into the search bar and hit Enter. In the System Properties window, click “Environment Variables.”. Remove old paths that point to user-installations.
10. from explorer, run webui-user.bat the script will run very long and download some gigabytes (~5GB) then it will seem to stop at something like

````
To create a public link, set `share=True` in `launch()`.
Startup time: 259.9s (import torch: 3.4s, import gradio: 9.4s, import ldm: 1.1s, other imports: 3.5s, list SD models: 153.8s, setup codeformer: 0.4s, load scripts: 1.8s, load SD checkpoint: 86.0s, create ui: 0.3s, gradio launch: 0.2s).```
````

That's it, the web-ui should now be accessible at http://127.0.0.1:7860
(If the web-ui doesn't start to create images, check if you selected anything in the console window. that will block the server. Just press ESC to remove any text selections)

- It doesn't seem to matter, which minor version of python 3.10 you install.
- It does matter that you install as admin for all users.
- It does matter that you have the path set to the system installation, e.g. `C:\Program Files\Python310` (good) and NOT to your users installation directory `C:\Users\you\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` (bad)

Answer (score 1):

Same issue when doing a fresh install of SD.

1. Copied the Stable Diffusion via GIT into the running folder I chose
2. Ran the WebUI-User.bat file.
3. Unable to install torch or pyvision like above.

To Troubleshoot I checked the Python version:
Start -> Run -> "cmd"
type: "python --version"

found to be 3.10.11 version.
Uninstalled Python 3.10.11 and installed 3.10.6

Tried to run again, PATH error where Python was not located for 3.10.11

Went into environment and removed the reference to the 3.10.11

Tried again with success to run the WebUI-User.bat file.

Answer (score 1):

What I finally discovered: Torch does not support newer versions of Python.
I mistakenly assumed that semver rules applied so I did not think there would be much difference between Python 3.11.2 and Python 3.10.6.

However Torch will only install under the older version.
If you have the newer version installed, it will not give you any useful error message, it will just say "Torch package not found".

In hindsight that means "Torch package not found *for this version of Python*".

This is probably very obvious for people who use Python a lot, and not at all obvious for the rest of us.

Note: under windows you may also need to delete pip and python folders in `%AppData%`, and you should also delete the `venv` folder inside your stable diffusion folder.

Answer (score 1):

[ill share with you the method that worked for me....first thing open up the location you stored stable diffusion at, see the first pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ydXv.png)

[then click on top and type cmd and hit enter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjhum.png)
[after that in the console window type the first command that i pointed then it turned out that the pip needs to be updated ,look at the second command i pointed and type it, it should update the pip after it finishes close the window and now you can run the webui-user.bat folder and the download will continue without any problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DLcmw.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem on Unbuntu and solved it by deleting the venv folder inside stable-diffusion-webui then recreating the venv folder using virtualenv specifically. So:

1. `pip install virtualenv` (if you don't have it installed)
2. `cd stable-diffusion-webui`
3. `rm -rf venv`
4. `virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.10 venv`
5. `bash webui.sh`

And everything worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

hello my friend i have fixed it in a very easy way try this in your cmd

E:\stab.e difusion\SUPER SD 2.0 Dependencies\stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

just change the directory to match yours

Comment: The OP said they already did that!

Answer (score 0):

Has same problem. Guys, check in apps if you have another python installed too and delete it)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this is how I solved it.

1. I uninstalled python 3.10.10, installed 3.10.6
2. I ran `py -m ensurepip` inside `stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts` and got another error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\(USERNAME)\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
(...)
```

3. I manually downloaded `get-pip.py` and ran `py get-pip.py` inside `stable-diffusion-webui\venv\Scripts`
4. I ran `webui-user.bat` and it works

Hope this helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake I did was using PowerShell, it didn't work with that but installation works fine with Command Prompt (CMD)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had multiple versions of python installed one on C: and various versions in C:\msys64\mingw64\bin. What i did was removed the python versions in mingw64 folder and then also uninstalled python that was installed on C:, then did a fresh install of C:, git cloned stable diffusion and webui user bat file is working now.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem by doing this:

1. cd /home/ubuntu/stable-diffusion-webui/venv/bin
2. python3 --version
   Python 3.10.6
3. python3 -m pip install torch

If you haven't installed python3-pip yet, you have to do that first from apt install command.